# Recursive query by multiple relations Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to perform a recursive query with some kind of intersection. I have a node with Device label and there are such fields like - device_id, column1, column2, column3
I need to find all the records of the Device node which are connected by column1 equality, then find the connection for other nodes by column2 with results of the previous query, and the last step is to find the connection by column3 between the results of the 2nd query with all the other nodes.
I have created separate relationships for that which would connect the nodes by the equality of column1, column2, and column3.

How can I write this query?

I tried to design something like thism but this query returns too many results and simple filters on the data in Excel show that the results are wrong:

```
MATCH (d:Device)-[:DEV_COLUMN1]->(d1:Device)-[:DEV_COLUMN2]->(d2)-[:DEV_COLUMN3]->(d3)
RETURN distinct d3.device_id, collect(distinct d3.column1), collect(distinct  d3.column2), collect(distinct d3.column3)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe and this pattern `(d:Device)-[:DEV_COLUMN1]->(d1:Device)-[:DEV_COLUMN2]->(d)-[:DEV_COLUMN3]->(d1)`, I see a mistake : you are using twice the variables `d` and `d1`.

From what I understand your pattern should be : `(d:Device)-[:DEV_COLUMN1]->(d1:Device)-[:DEV_COLUMN2]->(d2)-[:DEV_COLUMN3]->(d3)`

Comment: I`ve updated the query in my question, however, it doesn't change the results. The problem is that for each step of the query I need the results from the previous step

Comment: OK but it's not a problem, `(((a+b)+c)+d)` can be written like that `a+b+c+d`. So normally with my pattern you should have the good result. Are you sure that yours relationships are correct ?